# Write to CSV and read it back to dataframe

Tags: csv, pyspark

I need to read rather big data from MySQL, write it to file for optimized further work - and then work with this file.

But Spark creates not one file - but the whole folder. I can figure out the exact name of the file - but may be spark has proper way to get df from file that was just written?

Comment: Writing just one file is not a distributed fault tolerant code. But if you must, you can convert spark dataframe to pandas and then write out pandas dataframe into a csv.

Comment: @user238607 yes, its a very good point, so what is a proper processs for temporary store data in cvs? Or pyspark for the big data frames will automatically dump them on disk?

Comment: Each executor writes a csv file for partitions it is given to handle inside the folder. You can easily read all these files from any tool you are using. All tools should support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark will always create a folder but you can force it to push data to one file by using `coalesce()`. This way data will be repartitioned:

```py
df.coalesce(1).write.csv("file_name")
```